# Using proper syntax in expression builder

Tags: ms-access-2010

Am new to Access.

Have a field on a form called Surname.
I would like to add an expression to the AfterChange event for this field that would change its field to say uppercase.
What should the expression say? (once I get the syntax correct I will then be able to work out how to build it).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to do this in VBA quiet easily I would guess. Not sure if Expression builder would be able to do that for you. With VBA you will use,

```
Private Sub yourControlName_AfterUpdate()
    Me.yourControlName = UCase(Me.yourControlName)
End Sub
```

If you are new to VBA, then check out how to write your very first VBA code : www.baldyweb.com/FirstVBA.htm

Hope this helps !